# Accessing 'this' object properties inside each loop

Tags: javascript, mootools

Whats the best way to access *testval* and *testoption* inside the foreach loop? This is a mootools draft.

```
var some = new Class({
   options: { testarray: [1,2,3], testoption: 6 },       
   initialize: function(options) {
      this.testval = '123';
      this.options.testarray.each(function(el) { 
         console.log(this.testval);
         console.log(this.options.testoption);
      });
    } 
});
```

**UPDATE:**
I can fix it by adding bind(this) on the array, but is that the way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases where I need to reference a number of instance variables from a function that makes `this` refer to something else I often use `var self = this;` just before. I find it reads a lot better than binding things all over the place; the `self` becomes explicitly clear to refer to the instance.

Answer (score 2):

yes, the mootools way to do this is to bind your functions either with

```
this.options.testarray.each(function(el) { 
  console.log(this.testval);
  console.log(this.options.testoption);
}.bind(this));
```

or by using the `Binds` mutator (available in Mootools More, thanks @Dimitar Christoff)

```
var some = new Class({
 options: { testarray: [1,2,3], testoption: 6 },
 Implements: Optons,
 Binds: ['logOption'],
 initialize: function(options) {
   this.testval = '123';
   this.setOptions(options);
   this.options.testarray.each(this.logOptions);
 },
 logOptions : function(value, index, array) {
   // I don't really see the point, but here you are, this code will be executed
   // three times, with (1, 0, [1,2,3]), (2, 1, [1,2,3]) and (3, 2, [1,2,3])
   console.log(value, index, array);
   console.log(this.testval);
   console.log(this.options.testoption);
 }
});
```

I moved your each (and not forEach, as said in the comments) inside the initialize(), since I'm not sure code inside the class descriptor object mill work... Also you might want to use the passed options in initialize with `this.setOptions(options)` and implementing the Options mutator.

Also, as noted in every comment you have `var self = this;` which is very convenient AND readable.

Comment: The 'mootools' way is to use .each (api) and not .forEach (not in old ie). 2nd arg after fn is context. But `self = this` is preferred by most.

Comment: ah yes I didn't even notice the forEach... And you're right most use the `self = this` method. I have a soft spot for binding, especially since I had such a hard time wrapping my head around it at the time.

Comment: The method is still valid though, once I've removed all my errors :)

Comment: yes, totally - bind is pretty good when native fn.proto.bind but I do not like the `binds mutator` for readability. Same as I don't like `_.bindAll`, needs to die as a pattern! you should change it to say it's a `mootools-more` thing.